# client-side array in the OpenGL 3.3. core

Tags: opengl, c++

It is possible the topic (not using VBO)?

in the OpenGL 3.0 compatible profile I can to draw this way:

```
GLint position_index = attrib_location_get("VertexPosition");
gl::EnableVertexAttribArray(position_index);
gl::VertexAttribPointer(position_index, 3, gl::FLOAT, false, 0, pos_Data);
gl::DrawArrays(gl::TRIANGLES, 0, count_of_vertices);
```

Bat in the OpenGL 3.3 core profile it displays a blank screen. It is right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, this is correct**.

From the [OpenGL 3.3 specification](https://khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec33.core.pdf), section E.2.2: Removed Features:

> Client vertex and index arrays - all vertex array attribute and element array index pointers must refer  to buffer objects.   The default vertex array object (the name zero) is also deprecated.  Calling VertexAttribPointer
>   when no buffer object or no vertex array object is bound will generate an
>   INVALID_OPERATION error, as will calling any array drawing command when no vertex array object is bound.

Answer (score 0):

We're missing half the example here, but I assume you are trying to display directly from a RAM-stored buffer.

This is simply not possible in core profile. You need to upload your data into VRAM via a VBO, *then* display it from there.

Comment: I don't think the data has to actually be in VRAM to render. That's driver's business.